# Show that f is continuous on x if and only if x is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $f : [0, 1] → R$ be given by the formula
>
> $f(x) = \frac{1}b$ if $x = \frac{a}b$, where $a$ and $b$ have no common factor,
>
> $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ irrational.
>
> Show that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $x$ is irrational. (Hint: Use the
> density properties of rationals and irrationals.)

**My attempt:** Let $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose $x$ is irrational, then $f(x) = 0$.

$|x-x| < \delta$

$|f(x) - x| = |-x| = x$

So we can choose $\delta = \epsilon$ so that $\epsilon > x$ (I'm unsure of this part).

Suppose $x$ is rational, $f(x) = \frac{1}b$. We want to show that is discontinuous. Suppose there is a $\delta$ that works for $|\frac{1}b-x| < \epsilon$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}2$. Let $x= \min(\delta, \frac{3}4)$

$|\frac{1}4 - \frac{3}4| = |-\frac{1}2| = \frac{1}2$

And $1/2$ is not greater than a $1/2$. So it is a contradiction.

Comment: I also tried graphing it, and it ended up looking like a ruler (inches).

Comment: I have a feeling you got the definition of continuity incorrect

Comment: In the line $|f(x)-x|$

Comment: Aren't we checking if it is continuous at x? So I thought you replace c with x... 
How would you use it?
Thank you.

Comment: Definition of continuity:

$f:[0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous at some $x \in [0,1]$ iff

$$\forall \; \epsilon >0 \; \exists \; \delta>0 \; | \; |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 6):

For $x_0\in [0,1]$, we want to show $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $x_0$ is irrational.

First suppose $x_0\in [0,1]$ is rational.

Then $f(x_0) > 0$.

Since the irrationals are dense in $[0,1]$, there is a sequence $t_1,t_2,t_3,... \in [0,1]$ of irrational numbers such that $t_n$ approaches $x_0$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

So we have ${\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}t_n}}=x_0$, 
but
${\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}f(t_n)}}=0 \ne f(x_0)$, hence $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$.

Next suppose $x_0\in [0,1]$ is irrational.

Necessarily $x_0\in (0,1)$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.

Choose an integer $B > {\large{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}}$.

There are only finitely many rationals in $(0,1)$ with denominators less than $B$, hence for some $\delta > 0$, we have an interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta) \subset (0,1)$ which contains none of them.

If $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ and $x$ is irrational, then $f(x) = 0$.

If $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ and $x$ is rational, then $0 < f(x) \le {\large{\frac{1}{B}}} < \epsilon$.

In either case, $|f(x)| < \epsilon$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&|x-x_0| < \delta\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|f(x)| < \epsilon\\[4pt]
\implies\;&|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was so clear and made so much sense! Thank you, thank you!

Comment: How do we know there are only finitely many rationals in $(0,1]$ with denominators less than $B$?

Comment: @Al Jebr: For any fixed positive integer $b \le B$, the rationals in $(0,1]$ with denominator _equal_ to $b$ are the fractions of the form $\frac{a}{b}$, where $1 \le a \le b$, so there are only $b$ choices for $a$.

Comment: How is $f$ not defined for $0$? Why do we want $(0,1]$ and not $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Al Jebr: Yes, my mistake -- I'll fix it -- thanks.

Comment: @quasi Second part was insane. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we need to restrict the domain to $(0,1]$ or the function is not well-defined.

For any $x$ we can say $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for all sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $x_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This defintion should be easier to use.

Suppose $x$ is irrational and $x_n \rightarrow x$ as described. If only finitely many $x_n$ are rational we note that $f(x_m)=0$ for high enough $m$ so we may assume without loss of generality that each $x_n$ is rational and $x_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ where $a_n$ cannot divide $b_n$. If $b_n$ is bounded then this will force $b_m =b$ and $a_m =a$ for high enough $m$ (why is this true?) and $x=\frac{a}{b}$, thus $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is unbounded. If $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has a bounded subsequence then $(x_n)$ would have a limit point that is rational by a similar reason given above (yet again, why must this hold?) and so $b_n \rightarrow \infty$. It now follows that $f(x_n) = b_n \rightarrow 0 = f(x)$ as required.

Now suppose $x$ is rational. We now note that are the irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence of irrationals $(x_n)$ where $x_n \rightarrow x$, then $f(x_n)=0$ and $f(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $f(x) \neq 0$, thus $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Comment: I think that reasoning about continuity using sequential continuity is often very convenient. But in this example, I think it obscures the main point that rational numbers $x$ very close to irrational numbers $\xi$ have large denominators and hence small values of $f(x)$.

Comment: @RobArthan I do see your point, that property is slightly hidden in my proof and seeing that property does seem to be the essence of the argument.

Comment: How is the function not well-defined on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @AlJebr I erroneously thought that we could not define a coprime pair $a,b$ such that $0=a/b$. Clearly $a=0$ and $b=1$ will satisfy so $f(0)=1$. My proof will still work in this case.

Comment: Right. I first thought it was because $0=0/a\mapsto 1/a$ and $0=0/b\mapsto 1/b$, but actually $0/x$ is not in lowest terms since $x \mid 0$ and $x\mid x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint if $x= a/b \in [0, 1]$ is rational, then, because the irrational numbers in $[0, 1]$ are dense, there are irrational numbers $y$ arbitrarily close to $x$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| = |1/b -0| = 1/b$. If $x \in [0, 1]$ is irrational, then for any given $B$, the rational numbers in the interval $(x - 1/B, x + 1/B)$ all have the form $a/b$ with $b > B$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0$ an irrational number in $[0,1]$. You have to show that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)=0$. This is obvious for irrational $x$s, so all you have to prove is
$$\lim_{\substack{x\to x_0\\x\in\mathbf Q}}f(x)=0.$$
In terms of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$, this means that, for any  $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$  such that
$$\biggl|\frac ab -x_0\biggr|<\delta \implies 0<\frac1b <\varepsilon,\enspace\text{i.e. }\; b>\frac1\varepsilon. $$

Indeed, there is only a finite number of positive integers $\le\dfrac1\varepsilon$. Therefore, by the  *Archimedes property*, the interval $[0,1]$ contains only a finite number of rational numbers $\dfrac ab$ in irreducible form with denominator  $\le\dfrac1\varepsilon$.

Choose  $\delta>0$  small  enough so the interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ contains none of these fractions. Then all rational numbers $\dfrac ab$ in this interval have denominator $ b>\dfrac1\varepsilon$, hence
$$f\Bigl(\frac ab\Bigr)=\frac1b<\varepsilon.$$

The other way (continuous at $x$ implies $x$ irrational) is obvious  by contrapositive and density of the irrational numbers.